# Использование слова «сложносочиненный» (вне связи с ССП)

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, терминология, части-речи, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Читаю книгу Людмилы Мартовой «Первый шаг к мечте».

> 1. *До женитьбы Чарушин обычно ел без церемоний, но сейчас ему это все очень нравилось — и негнущаяся салфетка, и **[сложносочиненный](https://mybook.ru/author/lyudmila-martova/pervyj-shag-k-mechte/read/)
>      завтрак**, и то, что его нельзя съесть без ножа, просто вилкой.*
> 2. *Нина уже освоилась настолько, что не только перестала напряженно следить за ногами, но и вертела головой по сторонам, обращая внимание
>      на красногрудых снегирей, развешанные на деревьях симпатичные кормушки
>      с зернами внутри, на обледеневшие, словно стеклянные, ветки, голубую
>      бесконечность неба и **[сложносочиненную](https://iknigi.net/avtor-lyudmila-martova/159058-pervyy-shag-k-mechte-lyudmila-martova/read/page-4.html) вязь крон**, раскиданную
>      по нему.*

Возник ряд вопросов.

Правильно ли написано слово ***сложносочиненный*** (слитно) в этих контекстах?
В каком **значении** оно здесь использовано? Какой **частью речи** является?
**Как называется** такое слово, которое уже есть в языке, но его значение-употребление словарями не зафиксировано?

Comment: Римма Михайловна, а почему слитное написание вас смущает?

Comment: Я бы на месте Людмилы Мартовой не стала бы два раза  в одной книге употреблять эту метафору. Уж слишком она заметная, произвести впечатление может сначала, но потом воспринимается как своеобразная тавтология.

Comment: В каком значении использовано: «необычный, замысловатый», но, по -моему, плохо звучит, вычурно, словно человек не смог найти нужного прилагательного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ исправлен.

1) О термине ***сложносочиненный***

В языке существует слово "сложносочиненный". Это  – **лингвистический термин**. В современной орфографии – здесь слитное написание термина, образованного **путем сращения.** Впрочем, правило это было введено еще **в 1956 году**, где  говорится о слитном написании терминологических выражений (индоевропейский, например).

Надо сказать, что сочетание "сложносочиненное предложение" раньше писалось **через дефис,** например в статье Поспелова можно прочитать: "Возьмем простейшие образцы сложно-сочиненного предложения". Источник: Поспелов Н.С. Статья в сборнике: Вопросы синтаксиса современного русского языка / Под ред. В.В. Виноградова. — М., 1950. (Так писалось бы  слово, образованное по  схеме "сложное сочиненное — сложно-сочиненное"). В дальнейшей литературе по этой теме мы встречаем уже слитное написание именно термина — ***сложносочиненный***.

**Примечание.** История этого термина весьма интересна. Надо сказать, что само понятие "сложное предложение" появилось не так давно, до этого существовало название "сложное целое". Да и смысл тоже оспаривался, то есть в сложном предложении не видели нового качества — этого единого целого. Разделение предложений на разные виды тоже пришло не сразу. А **однородность** современного сложносочиненного предложения  вообще уже чисто современное понимание.

2) Итак термин есть, **но нужен ли нам термин с его слитным написанием**? Не лучше ли сказать "сложно сочиненная вязь"? **Чем не метафора?**  Обычно сочиняют оперу, балет или стихи. А здесь мы сочиним вязь, букет или ужин. И даже человека можем сочинить! То есть значение в современном языке в любом случае будет переносное.

Вряд ли это **катахреза,** так как **нет здесь противоречия.** https://otvet.mail.ru/question/74215402

3) **Но можно ли написать это словосочетание раздельно** – *сложно сочиненный*? Так, сочетание *сложно переплетенный* пишется раздельно, например: "В них всегда имеется много параллельных и *сложно переплетенных* цепей питания". Но это обычное сочетание, а у нас – метафора!

И поэтому **мы заимствуем у термина только его слитную форму письма** (тоже своеобразный приемчик), в этом и состоит вся необычность ситуации. И пишем  – ***сложносочиненный***.

4) В словаре фиксируются только языковые метафоры, но не авторские. Со временем метафора может стать таковой, но далеко не всегда.  Хотя эта метафора используется **разными авторами**, но она вряд ли имеет перспективу развития, так как слишком необычна. Жизнь у таких слов недолговечна.

[Примеры из Нацкорпуса](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Comment: И ещё слово "вязь", тоже относящееся к письму, использовано нестандартно.

Answer (score 1):

Это метафора (перенос значения по сходству), чтобы обозначить нечто вычурное (как завтрак из примера) или сложное, запутанное (как кроны). Поэтому нет причин не писать его слитно, как слово-источник из грамматики.

В первом примере также заметна ирония, а во втором - [катахреза](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0) (кроны никто не сочинял).

По-моему, в обоих примерах есть нелепое желание щегольнуть словом подлиннее, как это бывает, когда говорят (неверно) "нелицеприятный" вместо "неприятный", "немаловажный" вместо "важный", "законодательство" вместо "закон" и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.