# Пунктуация в сложном предложении. Согласование сказуемого

Tags: пунктуация, согласование, сложное-предложение, единственное-множественное-число

Читаю книгу Людмилы Мартовой [«Первый шаг к мечте»](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=616066&p=8).
Возникло много вопросов. Вот второй.
[Первый (исправленный) — [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458159/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%9F).]

> В Знаменское удалось добраться ближе к вечеру. Решение ехать далось Чарушину нелегко. В нем **боролся** природный скепсис, утверждающий, что все Татины страхи — всего лишь причуды капризной богатенькой барышни[**?**] и чутко настроенный внутренний барометр, работающий на отличной интуиции, которая твердила, что в деле с наследством Липатова, возможно, не все чисто.

Чувствую, что на месте указанного вопросительного знака должен быть *хоть какой-нибудь* знак препинания. Только тире, только запятая или запятая и тире? Подскажите.

И еще. Думается мне, что надо использовать множественное число сказуемого — *боролись*.
[Проштудировала [видеотьютор](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/197-soglasovanieskazuemogospodlegawim.html) ("Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим"), но так и не смогла выбрать подходящее правило. Права я или нет?]

Comment: Римма Михайловна, запятая нужна. У Розенталы этот случай есть. Откройте тему СПП, там найдете. Мне с/ф трудно дать развернутый ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Меня смутило отсутствие знака вообще. А по поводу согласования есть у Вас точка зрения? Мнения-то противоположные.

Comment: Римма Михайловна, простите за опоздание с ответом. Не было возможности ответить. Я за мн. ч. Мн.ч. показывает, что сказуемое относится к каждому однородному члену.

Answer (score 3):

*В нем **боролись** природный скепсис, **утверждающий, что все Татины страхи — всего лишь причуды капризной богатенькой барышни**, и чутко настроенный внутренний барометр, работающий на отличной интуиции, которая твердила, что в деле с наследством Липатова, возможно, не все чисто.*

1) Ставится **только запятая**, закрывающая распространенный **причастный оборот**, в который входит и придаточное. Тире стоит в придаточном предложении между подлежащим и сказуемым (страхи —  причуды).

2) Лучше использовать **мн. число** для сказуемого. Почему? В таком распространенном предложении читатель должен **заранее понимать его структуру** и смысл, еще не дочитав до конца. А смысл состоит в том, что в герое *боролись два чувства.*

Answer (score 2):

На этом месте обязательно должна быть запятая, закрывающая придаточное. Вставкой (чтобы поставить тире или тире с запятой) часть после тире быть не может, так как при её изъятии предложение "ломается".

Розенталь:
При прямом порядке главных членов пред­ложения (сказуемое следует за однородными
подлежащими, соединёнными союзом и) обыч­но употребляется форма множественного чис­ла сказуемого, при обратном порядке (ска­зуемое предшествует однородным подлежа­щим) — форма единственного числа. Сравните:
*Книга и тетрадь лежали на столе.

На столе лежала книга и тетрадь.*
[http://journal.pushkin.institute/archive/archive/1977/77-06/Согласование%20сказуемого%20с%20подлежащим.pdf](http://journal.pushkin.institute/archive/archive/1977/77-06/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC.pdf)

Примечание для обратного порядка: чем дальше второе подлежащее от первого, тем менее актуальным (звучащим) является согласование во множественном числе.