# Можно ли сотворить руины?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

Читаю книгу Людмилы Мартовой [«Первый шаг к мечте»](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=74305&p=31).
Возникло много вопросов. Вот третий. (Если интересно, [№ 1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458159/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%9F) и [№ 2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458263/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).)

> — Жизнь вообще очень многообразна в своих проявлениях. В ней есть и во-первых, и во-вторых, и в-третьих… Я уверен, что сам Липатов не хотел бы наказания для членов своей семьи. Он бы их простил. Даже своего убийцу.
>   — Тата считает по-другому.
>   — Да, конечно. Иначе бы она вас не наняла. Но Тата всего лишь девочка, не знающая жизни. **Она не понимает, каково это — жить на руинах, которые ты сам же и сотворил.** А Липатов понимал. В этом разница.

Посмотрела в словарях значение глагола [сотвори́ть](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/248447/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — нужного не подобрала. (Может быть, опять что-то метафорическое?)
Как вы считаете, правильно ли говорить "сотворить руины"?

Answer (score 2):

*Она не понимает, каково это — жить **на руинах**, которые ты сам же и **сотворил.***

**Можно ли сотворить руины?** Вот, к примеру, создать их очень легко. Чтобы убедиться в этом,  достаточно набрать в поисковике фразу "как создать руины".

Пример: **Стильные руины в дизайне сада.** Стильные руины можно создать из клинкера, камня или бетона, облицованного камнем. Выбор за вами! Важно: чтобы **«сложносочиненная»** конструкция выглядела естественно, перед ее сборкой проконсультируйтесь у профессионалов.

В приведенной фразе **обычное переносное (метафорическое) значение.** Ну а глагол *сотворить* используется в значении *создать*: СОТВОРИТЬ, -1. кого-что. **Книжн.** **Создать** в процессе творчества.   Для метафоры вполне подходит.

Но, может быть, нас будет смущать **сочетаемость слов** *сотворить руины*? Но в приведенном предложении они рядом  не стоят и  наш слух не напрягают. А сочетание "которые сотворил" кажется вполне освоенным и привычным.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Более привычным было бы выражение ***превратить в руины*,** но в нем нет явно выраженного значения преднамеренности действия. Например: *Во что ты превратил свою комнату!* Но ведь беспорядок так часто создается незаметно, как бы сам по себе.

***Сотворить же руины*** можно только целенаправленно, когда человек осознает возможный результат своих действий, но при этом не старается что-то изменить. Здесь, я думаю, яснее выражен нравственный упрек.

Answer (score 1):

> Как вы считаете, правильно ли говорить "сотворить руины"?

Такое сопоставление противоречивых понятий — распространённый в литературе приём, имеющий своё название: **оксюморон**. Очевидно, что данный приём автор использовал сознательно, а не по ошибке. Поэтому говорить здесь лучше не о том, правильно это или нет, а о том, уместен ли такой приём в данном контексте (почему бы и нет?).

Другие известные примеры использования этой фигуры речи: *горячий снег, "обыкновенное чудо, мёртвые души* и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Звучит оригинально и как-то пафосно.

Здесь смысл переносный: своими действиями привёл к разрушению того, что окружает (например, карьера, дружба, возможности, талант, достойная жизнь, авторитет, бизнес). То есть творец такого результата.

Answer (score 0):

В целом звучит, конечно, не вполне корректно. Если бы это был авторский текст, то можно было считать это за ошибку.

Но это прямая речь, так что такое словоупотребление может служить для речевой характеристики персонажа. Даже по этому короткому отрывку видно, что он любит «задвигать» умные речи про смысл жизни и использовать красивые слова даже там, где они не вполне уместны. Так что это может быть стилистическим заданием.

Answer (score 0):

Само по себе выражение персонажа (разумеется, автору можно в его уста вложить всякое) выглядит *двусмысленным* - вне контекста неясно, что именно он пытался сказать:

- жить на *руинах* чего-либо самим человеком *сотворённого*
- жить на чём-то собственноручно *превращённом в руины*