# Слово «свет», относящееся к отчеству. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, ономастика

Прочитала книгу Людмилы Мартовой [«Первый шаг к мечте»](https://books.google.ee/books?id=zihgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT104&lpg=PT104&dq=%C2%AB%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=0VnODacdBi&sig=ACfU3U2uun3-QQ8yJ6TmpqKCsgFuVAqJYA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFyeqMitTnAhUB06YKHUQLDMcQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%C2%AB%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false).
Вот очередной вопрос. (Предыдущие — [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458316/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B).)

> «По закону подлости именно сейчас мне должен позвонить Сергей, — с некоторой долей юмора подумала она. — Меня обнаружат, выволокут на свет божий, начнут проводить расследование, отчего я пугаю пожилых леди рано утром. *И если **Вера, свет, Георгиевна** от моего вызывающего поведения не помрет от разрыва сердца, то я еще легко отделаюсь.* Может, хоть пытать не будут. А что, с этой семейки станется».

Не знаю почему, но слово ***свет***, обрамленное запятыми, у меня вызвало удивление.
Порылась в Нацкорпусе. Вот что обнаружилось.

**1.** *Ты куды же, горемыка, идешь?

Я иду-ползу на барский двор,

Ко **Агафье свет-Ивановне,**

К Серафиме Сарафановне.*
[В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&lex1=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&startyear=1844&lex2=%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&endyear=1864&mode=main&parent1=0&min2=1&nodia=1&parent2=0&docid=L3BsYWNlL3J1c2NvcnBvcmEvdGV4dHMvZmluYWxpemVkL21haW4vc291cmNlL3ByZTE5NTAveGl4L2tyZXN0b3Zza3kvdHJ1c2Nob2J5XzEtMy54bWwjMDAxNw==) (1864)

**2.** *Когда пожилая женщина утомилась и вышла из круга, отец переменил ритм гармонного перебора и понесся полом с выкриком в такт: **Ва-сенушку, Свет Григорьевну,** — вызывал он на танец невесту* ([К. С. Петров-Водкин. Моя повесть](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)  [1930]).

**3.** *С этой песней, **Людмила свет Петровна,** я кажинный божий день бужу всесоюзного соню Андрюшку Лузгина, умываю и одеваю его в пурпурные одежды, кормлю манной кашкой...* ([В. Липатов. И это все о нем](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) [1984])

**4.** *Хоть и уверена, что прибегание к цитатам сплошь и рядом свидетельствует не столько об образованности, сколько о неумении изъясниться выразительно и мудро, припадаю к вечному источнику: царственной универсальности **Пушкина Александра ― свет Сергеевича*** ([Г. Шергова. ...Об известных всем](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) [2002-2004]).

Хотелось бы знать ваше мнение — а как же правильно оформлять слово "свет" вкупе с отчеством?

Answer (score 3):

Свет-... (нар.-поэт. и разг.) — перед собственными именами и (чаще) отчествами пишется через дефис, напр.: свет-Наташа, свет-Ивановна, Иван свет-Андреевич, Катеринушка свет-Васильевна.

Научно-информационный «Орфографический академический ресурс АКАДЕМОС» Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН.

(Сведения с Грамота.ру.)